# Laravel find records between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

i am doing below coding for find records between two dates in laravel 
but its not giving today's created_at records

```php
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->get('start_date')));

$end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->get('end_date')));

$shipments = Shipments::with(['pick_up_address', 'delivery_address', 'empty_return', 'empty_pick_up'])->get();

if($request->has('start_date') && $request->has('end_date')) {
    $shipments = $shipments->where('created_at', '<=', $end_date)->where('created_at', '>=', $start_date);
} else if($request->has('start_date')) {
    $shipments = $shipments->where('created_at', '>=', $start_date);
} else if($request->has('end_date')) {
    $shipments = $shipments->where('created_at', '<=', $end_date);
} else {
    $shipments = Shipments::with(['pick_up_address', 'delivery_address', 'empty_return', 'empty_pick_up'])->get();
}
```

created_at is timestamp.
my server timezone is UTC.
please give me proper solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include sample data for the `start_date` and `end_date` GET parameters.

Comment: Start with the sql. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: $start_date=11/23/2019                                                                                                    $end_date=11/24/2019

Comment: there is `whereBetween` btw

Comment: did u find your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You use `->get()` on the Eloquent\Builder first.
   then `where` will not working after `get()`.
2. Because your `created_at` is timestamp, so I think you need to convert `$end_date` to the end of day, and the `$start_date` to the start of day.

Try this code:

```php
$start_date = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($request->get('start_date')));

$end_date = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime($request->get('end_date')));

$shipments = Shipments::with(['pick_up_address', 'delivery_address', 'empty_return', 'empty_pick_up']);

if($request->has('start_date')) 
{

       $shipments->where('created_at', '>=', $start_date);
}

if ($request->has('end_date')) 
{
       $shipments->where('created_at', '<=', $end_date);
}

$shipments = $shipments->get();
```

Comment: it works fine, but problem is there it's not giving today's record .

Comment: @HinalShah is today between your `$start_date` and `$end_date`? I think what you want is if there's no `start_date` and `end_date`, return all shipments; if it has `start_date`, return shipment after `start_date`; if both there, return between.

Comment: @HinalShah I think your today is beyond the `$end_date` , but there are same date. So you need to convert it to the end of day. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Fine. It gives me today's record , but what can i do if start_date and end_date is find empty.

Comment: @HinalShah if `start_date` and `end_date` is empty, it returns all. if between `start_date` and `end_date` has no record, it return empty.

Comment: @HinalShah any other problems?

Comment: Yes, if start_date or end_date is empty it's not return all shipments

Comment: @HinalShah I thought `start_date` **and** `end_date` is both empty, then return all shipments. If you want **or**, then I change my answer.

Comment: @HinalShah I have changed it.

Comment: I have 4 cases:
                      1. only set start_date
                       2. only set end_date
                       3.  set start_date and end_date both
                       4. empty start_date and end_date

Comment: @HinalShah So this answer is 1. only set start_date then return greater than start_date, 2. only set end_date then shipments lower than end_date, 3 both set will return between 4. empty start and end will return all.

Comment: @HinalShah Plz accept this answer if it works to you.

Answer (score 2):

Simply Use this query

```
$shipments = DB::table('shipments')
->whereBetween('dates', [$startDate, $endDate])
->get();
```